# Injected service not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, angular-test

I am trying to test an Angular 6 component with a mocked service.

My intention with the code below is to have nested `describe` statements to allow different versions of a mocked service to return different results

The real service does some HTTP calls, whereas my mock returns an Observable with the data.

When I execute the test I see that Jasmine is trying to actually do the HTTP call and is ignoring my mock

```
// Core imports
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DebugElement, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

// Vendor imports
import { ToastrModule, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

// Project imports
import { FormComponent } from './form.component';
import { FormService } from "../../services/form.service";
import { DatastoreService } from "../../services/datastore.service";

describe('FormComponent', () => {

   let component: FormComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;
   let de: DebugElement;
   let el;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
      console.info('First setup of module');
      return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [HttpClientModule, FormsModule, ToastrModule.forRoot(), NgbModule.forRoot()],
         providers: [
            FormService,
            ToastrService,
            DatastoreService,
            {
               provide: ActivatedRoute,
                  useValue: {
                     params: {
                        subscribe: (fn: (value: Params) => void) => fn({
                           tab: 0,
                        }),
                     },
                     snapshot: {
                        url: [{path: 'worker'}],
                        queryParams: {table: 'portal', sysId: undefined}
                     },
                  },
               },
            ],
         declarations: [ FormComponent ],
         schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
      });
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
      console.info('establishing components');
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      de = fixture.debugElement;
      el = de.nativeElement;
   });

   describe('with a form layout containing an invalid element', () => {

      let FormServiceMock = class FormServiceMock {
         constructor() { console.info('instantiated'); }

         public getForm(table) {
            console.log('getForm called');
            return Observable.of({
               "table": "portalx",
               "schema": {
                  "name": {"title": "name", "element_type": "string"},
                  "suffix": {"title": "suffix", "element_type": "string"},
                  "active": {"title": "active", "element_type": "boolean"}
               }, "layout": ["name", "suffix", "notexists", "active"]
            });
         }
      };

      beforeEach( () => {
         console.info('Second re-setup of module');
         TestBed.resetTestingModule();
         return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [{ provide: FormService, useClass: FormServiceMock }]
         }).compileComponents();
      });

      fit('ngOnInit sets values correctly', inject([FormService], (service: FormService) => {

         console.info('hello world');
         component.ngOnInit();
         expect(component.portal).toEqual('worker');

      }));

   });

});
```

Running the jasmine test gives me

> Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) ERROR
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) ERROR Disconnectedundefined
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 1 of 37 (skipped 36)    SUCCESS (1.779 secs / 1.655 secs)
>       sNm6eZUIrnZxAOwqAAAI with id 92987428
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           INFO: 'First setup of module'
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           INFO: 'First setup of module'
>           27 05 2018 17:36:00.293:WARN [web-server]: 404:    /api/services/ui/form/portal
>           27 05 2018 17:36:00.551:WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/services/ui/form/portal
>           INFO: 'establishing components'
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           INFO: 'establishing components'
>           INFO: 'Second re-setup of module'
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           INFO: 'Second re-setup of module'
>           INFO: 'instantiated'
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           INFO: 'instantiated'
>           INFO: 'hello world'
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           INFO: 'hello world'
>           LOG: HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{}, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 404,
>   statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:9876/api/seLOG:
>   HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{},
>   lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 404,
>   statusText: 'Not Found', url:
>   'http://localhost:9876/api/services/ui/form/portal', ok: false, name:
>   'HttpErrorResponse', message: 'Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:9876/api/services/ui/form/portal: 404 Not Found',
>   error: 'NOT FOUND'}
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           LOG: HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{}, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 404,
>   statusText: 'Not Found', url:
>   'http://localhost:9876/api/services/ui/form/portal', ok: false, name:
>   'HttpErrorResponse', message: 'Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:9876/api/services/ui/form/portal: 404 Not Found',
>   error: 'NOT FOUND'}
>           LOG: HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{}, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 404,
>   statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:9876/api/seLOG:
>   HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{},
>   lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 404,
>   statusText: 'Not Found', url:
>   'http://localhost:9876/api/services/ui/form/portal', ok: false, name:
>   'HttpErrorResponse', message: 'Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:9876/api/services/ui/form/portal: 404 Not Found',
>   error: 'NOT FOUND'}
>           Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 0 of 37 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>           LOG: HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{}, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 404,
>   statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:9876/api/seChrome
>   66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 1 of 37 (skipped 36) SUCCESS (1.638 secs / 1.52 secs)

In that log output I see `Instantiated` which is in my mock constructor, but I don't see my `getForm` method being called, instead, the real one is called from the service.

> Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) ERROR Disconnectedundefined 27 05
>   2018 17:35:58.128:

```
INFO [Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.12.6)]:    Connected on socket
```

any help on this?

Comment: try this : inject([FormService], (service: FormServiceMock )

Comment: Hi - when I do that the variable name is not recognised. TS2304: Cannot find name "FormServiceMock". Thanks